# UWP GridViewItem shows Classname

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, uwp, datatemplate

I want to implement a `GridView` in UWP and each Item contains a `TextBlock`, `Checkbox` and two `ComboBox`.
What I'm getting at the moment is the Classname instad of the `GridViewItem`.
I think that could be resolved by a `DataTemplate` maybe?

**Xaml File:**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="CameraSettingsGridViewTemplate" x:DataType="local:CameraSetting">
        <GridViewItem>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Property}"/>
                <CheckBox/>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind Value1}"/>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind Value2}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </GridViewItem>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <GridView Name="CameraSettings" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{x:Bind CameraSettingsList}"></GridView>
</Grid>
```

The `DataTemplate` is an attempt by to solve the problem.

**CS File:**

```
  public sealed partial class CameraSettingsPage : Page {
    private ObservableCollection<CameraSetting> cameraSettingsList = new ObservableCollection<CameraSetting>();
    public ObservableCollection<CameraSetting> CameraSettingsList { get { return this.cameraSettingsList; } }
    public CameraSettingsPage() {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.cameraSettingsList = new ObservableCollection<CameraSetting>() {
            new CameraSetting() {
                Property = "prop1",
                Auto = new CheckBox(),
                Value1 = new ComboBox() { ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "1", "2" } },
                Value2 = new ComboBox() { ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "a", "b" } }
            }
        };
    }

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    }
}

public class CameraSetting {
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public CheckBox Auto { get; set; }
    public ComboBox Value1 { get; set; }
    public ComboBox Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

In the constructor i create an example `GridViewItem` within a `ObservableCollection` and take this as `ItemSource` for the `GridView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things going on here.  First, the GridView is showing the name of the class as it's not actually using the data template you've tried to setup.

You need to use `x:Key` and not `x:Name` for Resources and then set that resource as the `ItemTemplate` property for the GridView:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CameraSettingsGridViewTemplate" x:DataType="local:CameraSetting">
        <GridViewItem>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Property}"/>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Bind Auto}"/>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind Value1}"/>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind Value2}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </GridViewItem>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <GridView Name="CameraSettings" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{x:Bind CameraSettingsList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CameraSettingsGridViewTemplate}"></GridView>
</Grid>
```

The second issue, is that you don't recreate controls in your data model.  The point of binding and templates is that you can have your basic types in your model (like string option values and booleans), and then bind those to the UI elements that manipulate them.  So your data model should look more like this:

```
public class CameraSetting
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public bool Auto { get; set; }
    public List<string> Value1 { get; set; }
    public List<string> Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can fill it in, similar to what you had before:

```
    public ObservableCollection<CameraSetting> CameraSettingsList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<CameraSetting>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.CameraSettingsList.Add(new CameraSetting()
        {
            Property = "prop1",
            Auto = true,
            Value1 = new List<string>() { "Option 1", "Option 2" },
            Value2 = new List<string>() { "Option 3", "Option 4" },
        });
    }
```

I'd suggest looking at some of the [Binding Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlBind) provided by the platform and there's a good overview of these scenarios and the issue you ran into on the official [docs page for binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart).

Remember, if you want your data updated on model changes or reflected back to your model on user changes, you'll need to add a `Mode=OneWay` or `Mode=TwoWay` to your x:Bind expressions.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, works as i wanted and thanks for the sugessted pages to read :)

Comment: Hi, is it possible to update the View depending on a change of a Property? For example if i Bind the `IsEnabled` property of the `ComboBox` to the Auto Property, what means that the Auto `CheckBox` enables/disables the ComboBox. I added `INotifyPropertyChanged` functionality to my `CameraSettings` Class but it doesn't update. I also added the `Mode=TwoWay` property to the `CheckBox` and `ComboBox`.

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` or `DependencyProperty` should work, see the examples classes they use in the sample: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/XamlBind/cs/xBindSampleModel/Manager.cs https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/XamlBind/cs/xBindSampleModel/DOModel.cs

Comment: Yes, sorry i did it correct but i had a stupid mistake -.- Thank you anyway :)